# Why is it necessary to use a voltage limiter at the output port of a Schmitt trigger?

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, schmitt-trigger

Why is it necessary to use a voltage limiter at the output port of a Schmitt trigger? How are switching thresholds determined in various types of Schmitt triggers?

Comment: Can you provide a source for your premise? I'm not aware of any general need to use a voltage limiter for a schmitt trigger. You can google schmitt triggers to see how switching thresholds are determined

Comment: That voltage limiting function is not provided by a special circuit. A common circuit for making a Schmitt trigger uses a **comparator**, see: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/schmitt.html. Such a comparator cannot output a higher voltage than its positive supply rail voltage. It can also not output a lower voltage than its negative supply rail voltage. Those limitations already make the comparator's output **voltage limited**.

Comment: Think about what would happen if the output of the comparator could reach infinitely high or low voltages (the output is not voltage limited), what would that do to the upper and lower threshold voltages of the Schmitt trigger?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the assertion that something is necessary is contrary to the truth. This invalidates the question.